# How to find a position's coordinates with respect to some anchors on a canvas? (RectTransform.anchoredPosition3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an animation based UI layout (in Unity), where if you select an element, some UI object will warp into the center, and new elements will come out from the center to their respective positions.

Each of these UI elements are anchored, but they are all anchored to a different anchor-point. Some to the top left corner, some to the top right corner, some to the center of the left, etc.

Edit: This is a mobile phone/tablet application so it needs to accomodate different screen sizes and resolutions, so that is why I use anchors.

I would like to know the center point of my Canvas with respect to the anchors. This way I can easily `Vector3.Lerp/Slerp` between my goal position (this I have with respect to the anchors) and the center position.

So how do I find the correct `RectTransform.anchoredPosition3D` of the center of my canvas with respect to my anchors?

Here is an illustration of a possible set up, where I would like to `Vector3.Lerp` between a **UI element's** `RectTransform.anchoredPosition3D` and the **center's** `RectTransform.anchoredPosition3D`.

- Circle = Center
- Rectangles = UI element
- Triangles = Anchors
- Color code to match UI element with Anchor

[image]

Comment: Maybe an Animation with Animator is easier than a script animation?

Comment: @Everts My screen size is not fixed, because its mobile phone application. That is why I thought, it is better to use scripts, since then it will work for all screen sizes. Can I achieve the same flexible result with Animation with Animator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I position my UI elements in the Unity Editor to their correct places using anchors.

I have a controller for each UI element, with which on `Start()` I can store their UI Element's `RectTranform anchoredPosition3D` as its `endPosition`, which is the one I have set in the editor.

Then it moves the UI element to its `startPosition` by setting its `RectTransform.localPosition` to (for example) Vector3.zero, which will be the center of the canvas. This way, I can move it without thinking about anchors.

Next, I store the UI element's `RectTranform anchoredPosition3D` (which now, after the translation, has the correct coordinates with respect to its anchors) in `startPosition`.

In code it looks like this:

```
Vector3 startPos, endPos;
void Start() {
    rectTransform = this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();

    /* endPos will store the position, that I have set in the editor */
    endPos = rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D;

    /* now I translate the UI element to the center of the Canvas (locally -> 0,0,0) */
    rectTransform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    /* I store this position in startPos */
    startPos = rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D;
}
```

This way, I can Lerp between the two positions easily.

**Note:** you can also use `Vector2` for `startPos` and `endPos`, and `rectTransform.anchoredPosition` instead of `rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D`, because most probably you don't need the `z-axis` for your UI.

**WARNING:** if you use the above code in `Awake()`, then it will **NOT** work reliably! It will work in some cases, but not in others, because the startPos will not be correctly calculated.